Pair Trading - Spread noise from Log returns regression
I have an automated strategy that has been running "ok" for month and generates consistent profit on Perpetual swaps (cryptos).
However something annoys me: I calculate the spread based on the regression of log returns and it can often generates two opposite consecutive signals because of the noise. My spread is calculated on 30min timeframes from 200 historical candldes (roling windows). Are you guys familiar with such issue ? Is there a "best practice" to cancel or smoothen the noise ?
I had an idea to use the exponential moving average returns instead of the price itself but that sounds really bad.
Thanks in advance for sharing.

It's a problem with the instability of time-series regression. In regular regression, ( not time-series ), you usually estimate a regression once and that's it. Here you continue to update as new data comes in over time which causes the instability. I never figured out a way to handle it ? I think the only thing to do is decide on how much data to "exclude" as new data comes in. In other words, as a new week of data comes in, cut off the oldest week so that you keep using the same amount of data when you re-run your regression. Good question and I'm not sure that there's an answer.

Thanks for your feedback, yes I'm using a rolling window of 200 historical bars for example, so that woul automatically cut the oldest ones. I thought this could also be due to volatility spikes where the log returns would jump back and forth between buy and sell signals. So may be I should investigate a volatility filter or something. At least it's good to know that it's a common challenge (I thought this could be due to a mistake on my side)

volatility spikes are really just large movements in the price so I don't know how you'd handle that ? I never solved the problem so I can't say anything useful. But, for me, it's also nice to know that had others had the same problem. Also, don't do exponential smoothing because ES is really an ARIMA(0,1,1) so you'll be implicitly imposing a new model on the returns ( or I guess log prices because arima(0,1,1) is differencing ).
